# Setting initial value for timer -register name

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab

I have a timer in XC8 MPlab with PIC16F690 that is running great.

I want to change its initial value. I could not find how to set a value into its register so it starts from that value.

I'm looking for the syntax for that register to fill it with data.

```
         OPTION_REGbits.T0CS = 0;  //setting timer
         OPTION_REGbits.PSA = 0;   
         OPTION_REGbits.PS = 0b101;  //setting the pre scale 
         INTCONbits.T0IE = 1;       
         ei();           //enable interrupts
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, for most registers, you can access by the name like in datasheet with XC8. So the register for `Timer0` called `TMR0` in datasheet is also `TMR0` in XC8.

Your code can be rewritten like below:

```
T0CS = 0;    // setting timer
PSA = 0;   
PS = 0b101;  // setting the pre scale 
T0IE = 1;
TMR0 = 0x06;
ei();        // enable interrupts
```